# Сдвиг элементов двумерного массива по часовой стрелке (C++)

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Нужно сдвинуть элементы двумерного массива, на k элементов по часовой стрелке (С++).

```
1  1  1  1  
2  2  2  2  
3  3  3  3  
4  4  4  4
```

Допустим, на k = 2, тогда:

```
3  2  1  1   
4  3  3  1   
4  2  2  1    
4  4  3  2
```

**Вопрос**: можно ли здесь **использовать дополнительный массив** такого же размера, чтобы в него записывать уже перемещённые элементы?

С дополнительным массивом я уже сделал, но есть подозрение, что это лишнее, и что можно обойтись парой переменных без второго массива. Или, всё же, то, что есть дополнительный массив — нормально?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По идее, достаточно одной дополнительной переменной.

Для каждого цикла вы запоминаете первый элемент в эту переменную, затем копируете второй в первый, третий во второй и так далее, на место последнего записываете сохранённый первый.

Comment: Я тоже думал об этом варианте, теперь убедился что он подходит. И ещё, ваш вариант, для сдвига против часовой стрелки)

Comment: могу ошибаться но матрицу вроде можно вращать умножением https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86

Comment: @perfect: Нет, умножением реализовать вращение невозможно. Доказательство: При умножении матриц ранг не повышается (т. к. линейное преобразование не может поднять размерность линейной оболочки). Поворот же поднять ранг может. Пример:

    0  1  11      0   0   1
    0  2  12  ->  0   2  11
    0  3  13      3  13  12

Ранг первой матрицы 2, а второй — 3, т. к. у ней ненулевой детерминант.

Answer (score 0):

Сдвиг такого двумерного массива можно рассматривать как циклический сдвиг двух *линейных* последовательностей, образованных концентрическими "кольцами" в таком массиве. Алгоритмов циклического сдвига линейного массива без использования дополнительного массива - вагон и маленькая тележка. Не составит никакого труда "спроецировать" выполняемые такими алгоритмами перестановки прямо на "кольца" вашей матрицы, т.е. выполнить из прямо в вашей матрице.

Например, простейшим алгоритмом сдвига линейной последовательности длины `N` на `K` элементов вправо будет: зеркально перевернуть всю последовательность длины `N`, зеркально перевернуть начальную подпоследовательность длины `K`, зеркально перевернуть оставшуюся часть подпоследовательность длины `N - K`. Нет ничего сложного в том, чтобы напрямую выполнить эти перевороты в "кольцах" матрицы - надо только аккуратно пересчитать индексы.